# does the sequence converge

Tags: sequences-and-series

I would like to know whether the two sequences converge, and if yes where(limit). I´m not very sure about my reasoning...thx for any help:

1. Is the sequence $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ with $a_n := 2^{-n}$ convergent? If yes what is the limit?
2. Is the sequence $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ with $a_n := 2^{-(n-1)}$ convergent? If yes what is the limit?

For the $first$, I would say yes. It converges and has $3$ limits

- As $n$ goes to $\infty$ than I`ll get $\frac{1}{2^n}$, which is $\frac{1}{2^\infty}$. So the first limit is $0$
- As $n$ goes to $0$ than is $\frac{1}{2^n}$, which is $\frac{1}{2^0}$. So the second limit is $1$.
- As $n$ goes to $-\infty$ than I`ll get $\frac{1}{2^n}$, which is $\frac{1}{2^{-\infty}}$. So the third limit is  $\infty$.

For the $second$, I would say yes. It has one limit.

- As $n$ goes to $\infty$ than I`ll get $2^{1-n}$, which is  $2^{1-\infty}$, which is $\frac{1}{2^\infty}$. So the limit is $0$.

Comment: This feels cheap for an answer, so i wont post one:
I think it normally means as $n$ goes to infinity, when talking about convergence of sequences. so part (a.) you are gave correct for both are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Well strictly speaking you don't have only 3 limits. You can have a limit for $n\to 5$ for example. And that is also not really correct since n is an integer and is not real, so you cannot really get that close to $5$ or $0$ with $n$. But you can *calculate* the sequence term $a_n$ for $n=0$ or $n=1$ and so on. The limits for $n\to \infty$ are correct and both $0$ as you correctly noticed.

Comment: Hi Umberto, thx for your comment. This means that it doesnt converge because there is no unique value, or limit, for the whole sequence

Comment: Well the limit for $n\to \infty$ exists as you noticed. But to speak of a limit you need to satisfy some hypothesis. Check here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence. When you have sequences the only limits that make sense (as long as we move in the realm of integeres and reals) are for $\infty$ and $-\infty$.